# Pandas "cut" based on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use `pd.cut` (to convert continuous variables into discrete ones) in some variables of my pandas dataframe, but I want that cut to depend on other column. Imagine I want 3 bins.

For example:

```
+------+------+------+--------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | sector |
+------+------+------+--------+
| 4.5  | 6    | 7    | a      |
+------+------+------+--------+
| 8    | 9    | 17   | a      |
+------+------+------+--------+
| 0    | 9    | 8    | b      |
+------+------+------+--------+
| 8    | 9    | 0    | b      |
+------+------+------+--------+
| 1    | 2    | 3.5  | b      |
+------+------+------+--------+
```

I want to cut only `col1` and `col2` into 3 bins, based on `sector`, so that for each sector a cut is performed. This is very usefull to compare variables from different sources.

The result would be (it's made up, don't expect it to be 100% accurate):

```
+----------+----------+------+--------+
| col1_cut | col2_cut | col3 | sector |
+----------+----------+------+--------+
| 2        | 2        | 7    | a      |
+----------+----------+------+--------+
| 3        | 3        | 17   | a      |
+----------+----------+------+--------+
| 1        | 3        | 8    | b      |
+----------+----------+------+--------+
| 3        | 3        | 0    | b      |
+----------+----------+------+--------+
| 1        | 1        | 3.5  | b      |
+----------+----------+------+--------+
```

> PS: I made this Q&A because I had this problem and couldn't find a
>   solution myself. Feel free to answer your own solution or improve
>   mine, I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that can be shorten as

```
s=pd.concat([y[['col1','col2']].apply(pd.cut,bins=3,labels=False)for x, y in df.groupby('sector')])
s
Out[157]: 
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     2     2
2     0     2
3     2     2
4     0     0

df.update(s)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Great solution, but how do I preserve the rest of the columns, like in my solution ?

Answer (score 1):

To perform that operation, you only need:

```
col_add = []

sectors = df['sector'].unique()

for col in df.columns:
    if col in ['col1','col2']:
        col_add.append(col)
        df['{}_cut'.format(col)] = 0 # Initialized (not needed but I like to)
        for sector in sectors:
            df['{}_cut'.format(col)][df['sector'] == sector] = pd.cut(df[col][df['sector'] == sector], 3, labels=False)

df.drop(col_add, axis = 1, inplace = True) # Remove old cols
```